# Loading content with ajax and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have Ajax spinner show on specific page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063356/how-to-have-ajax-spinner-show-on-specific-page)

I have this nav menu with 2 tabs:

```
<div id="user_menu">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><%= link_to "Group1", group1_friends_path(@user), :remote => true %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Group2", group2_friends_path(@user), :remote => true %></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I've managed to let Ajax render certain partials. Now, when I click on the tabs the partials loads in my target placeholder div.

**tab.js:** which I placed in assest/javascripts/

```
$(function() {
    $('#user_menu a').click(function (e) {
        $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active')
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
        $("#friends-data").fadeOut(function(){
            $("#loading-indicator").fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

I don't like to show all the content all the same time and let the user wait for all the http request to render. I would like to show a loading bar and when all the http request is finished, hide the loadingbar and show the content.

Right know is more theatrical then functional. Any help, example would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the answer I gave to this other answer. Seems like it's what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063356/how-to-have-ajax-spinner-show-on-specific-page/11064973

Comment: @Ashitaka  thansk for the tip, but what I really want, is that ajax checks that every http request is finished then show the content and in the mean time show the loadingbar..

Comment: So... You don't want the user to click those remote links? You just want the page to render with some loading bars and then in the background load the partials, without any user interaction?

Comment: @Ashitaka What I mean is that if you want the best user experience one must have both.

Comment: When a user clicks those links, isn't the content loaded automatically already?

Comment: @Ashitaka I dont think you really understand my question and what I want to do.

Comment: I agree. But I assure you, the problem isn't on my end.