# Show loading image while performing an action

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a link on my control panel 
this link, call an action of my controller.

```
<%= link_to "Enviar Correos".html_safe, {:controller => "users", :action => "email_all_users"}, :method => "get", :html =>  {:style => "color:#FAA732;" } %>
```

the action:

```
def email_all_users
    User.all.each do |u|
        if !u.information.nil?
            if !u.information.business
                UserMailer.candidate_email(u).deliver
            else 
                    UserMailer.business_email(u).deliver
            end
        else
                UserMailer.no_info_email(u).deliver
        end
    end
    redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}",  :flash => { :success => "Los correos fueron enviados" }
  end
```

everything works great, but it's taking a lot of time, so after click on the link I would like to change the link for a loading image and then (when the action finish), I would like to show another imagen (done!) and then show the link.

I've never work with ajax. So I need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What client side technology are you using? (As showing/hiding) the loading image will be controlled by the client (browser). You may want to have a look at this : http://rails-learning.blogspot.in/2011/11/ajax-pagination-in-rails-3.html

Answer (score 0):

Generate loader image from Link

[Ajax Image Link](http://www.ajaxload.info/)

you need to write javascript to show the image on clicking the link

and hide image on load complete.

May this question work for you

[Link of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063356/how-to-have-ajax-spinner-show-on-specific-page)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in your link

```
:remote =>  true
```

to make an Ajax call.

Rails will go to "email_all_users". Here you will have to quit the "redirect_to" sentence.

Into your views you have to place a "JS" view file like "email_all_users.js.erb", here you could write the necesary javascript to show the info "Los correos fueron enviados".

To show the loading image with, for example jQuery, you can put something like this:

```
$('body').ajaxStart(function() {
    $('body>*:not(:hidden)').fadeTo(0, 0.5)
    $(this).append('<img id="ajax_loader" src="/images/loading.gif">')
});
$('body').ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('body>*:not(:hidden)').fadeTo(0, 1)
    $('#ajax_loader').remove()
});
```