# Get last ajax call in jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery, jasmine

I want to get last ajax call made in my code .

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
    function getCreateAccount() {
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/Account/Register/",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json"
         });
        console.log($.ajax.mostRecentCall.args[0]);
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

but when i see in my console it says "TypeError: $.ajax.mostRecentCall is undefined" .

Thanks,

Comment: try to use a flag variable

Comment: use `var ajaxcall = $.ajax({ type: "GET", ...` and try if you can use the ajaxcall variable to get the information you need

Comment: Is this post of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176956/get-latest-ajax-request-and-abort-others

Comment: Is this Jasmine framework? You don't seem to load Jasmine

Comment: do you want to know the most recent _initiated_ call, or the most recently _completed_ ?

Comment: I am working with jasmine , and this thing works perfectly in jasmine , but i want to get the same thing out of jasmine

Comment: @Alnitak most recently completed

Comment: @user2413182 and you're trying to replicate the Jasmine functionality, without using Jasmine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may register a global `ajaxComplete` handler that will be invoked every time an AJAX call finishes.

With this, you can emulate something like the Jasmine `$.ajax.calls.mostRecentCall()` property:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(ev, jqXHR, settings) {
    $.ajax.mostRecentCall = jqXHR;
});
```

In this case I'm saving the `jqXHR` object, rather than the exact set of parameters that was passed to `$.ajax`.

Note, of course, that this won't be populated immediately after `$.ajax` is called - it won't be filled until at least one call has finished.

Comment: No no no! If you initialise Jasmine properly, and call spyOn($, "ajax") beforehand, then it should work without any hacks!

Comment: @jackocnr note that the OP said they wanted to get this functionality _without_ using Jasmine.

Answer (score 3):

I think **mostRecentCall** function is from [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/downloads) framework. You must include Jasmine in your code.

**mostRecentCall** does not exist in jquery!

Answer (score 0):

there is no such this like "$.ajax.mostRecentCall" in ajax jquery.

As PSR mentioned you could try to use a flag variable

Comment: can you put something on fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alert before logging will give enough time for the ajax call to be finished.(that should do the trick)

if you don't want any alerts then you can use sleep() method

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like

```
$.ajax.mostRecentCall
```

in Jquery. That is from Jasmine.js. Unless and until you add reference to Jasmine.js and follow the steps to spy on function, it will give you an error.

You may want to refer the [documentation](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Spies) of Jasmin.js. Here's the [link](http://a-developer-life.blogspot.in/2011/06/jasmine-part-2-spies-and-mocks.html) that shows how to use it.